# How to create AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient without the deprecated warning?

Tags: amazon-web-services

There is an example for EnableDynamoDBAutoscaling in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/AutoScaling.HowTo.SDK.html.

However, using this example results in one deprecated warning for the line:

```
static AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient aaClient = new AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient();
```

How to avoid this deprecated warning?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, with endpoint configuration this code worked for me:

```
EndpointConfiguration endpointConfiguration = new EndpointConfiguration("http://localhost:8000",
        Regions.US_EAST_1.toString());
AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient aaClient = (AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient) AWSApplicationAutoScalingClientBuilder
            .standard().withEndpointConfiguration(endpointConfiguration).build();
```

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the [aws-sdk](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-java/blob/master/aws-java-sdk-applicationautoscaling/src/main/java/com/amazonaws/services/applicationautoscaling/AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient.java#L198) library source code, the call you're trying is deprecated, you'd want to use the following API

`AWSApplicationAutoScalingClientBuilder#defaultClient()`

e.g.

```
static AWSApplicationAutoScalingClient aaClient = AWSApplicationAutoScalingClientBuilder.defaultClient().build();
```

Comment: No, this does not work, please check compilation.  Also, if you can set EndPoint configuration, this will be great